# Same method called with different objects as parameter

Tags: java

I have a program that sends requests to a server. There are many different types of request, and each has their own class. For example, I have a `checkServerOnlineRequest` which sends a short message to the server, or a `getAmountOfGoldRequest` which sends a very different message.

```
class CheckServerOnlineReq{
    static final byte requestID = 1;
    byte[] message;

    void setMessage(byte messageNumber){
        message = new byte[2];
        message[0] = messageNumber;
        message[1] = requestID;
    }
}
```

To send the requests, I have a `Client` class. It has `static` method called `send` which I would like to accept any type of request (i.e. a number of different classes)

My question is, how can I set up `send()`'s parameters to allow any type of request to be given as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way is to declare an interface, and make the concrete request classes implement that interface:

```
public interface IRequest { ... }

public class CheckServerOnlineRequest implements IRequest { ... }
public class GetAmountOfGoldRequest implements IRequest { ... }
```

Then the `send()` method can accept `IRequest` as its argument.

```
public static void send(IRequest request) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your request classes should extend from a base `Request` class, that you define.  Your static method should take an argument of `Request request`.  Your base `Request` class (possibly abstract, possibly implementing an interface -- the details depend on what exactly is going on) should define all the methods Requests use, regardless of the actual type of the Request.

Failing that, your `send` method could take argument of the type `Object`, but that would be really bad, as you would only be able to access `Object` methods without casting.

Answer (score 1):

Make all requests subclass/implement a Request-class/interface, and make your send method have Request as argument.

E.g. class CheckServerOnlineReq extends/implements Request..

send(Request request)